# Cowboy: How can a cowboy handler reply back to client without request

Tags: erlang, cowboy

Now that Im using cowboy to serve as a websocket server, I understand that the handler implements a behavior called `cowboy_websocket_handler` and that the `websocket_handle/3` function is called every time we receive a request and that to reply back to the request, we reply using `{reply, X, _}`. However since WebSocket is a bi-directional protocol and that server can reach to a client without a request, how do I send some data to the client, not in the `web_socket_handle`.

I am expecting something in the handler along the lines of 
`send(Client, Data)`. Am I thinking in the right direction? ? Thanks!
If yes, does cowboy provide some API to do so?

Answer (score 1):

To quote the docs:

> Cowboy will call websocket_info/2 whenever an Erlang message arrives.
>
> The handler can handle or ignore the messages. It can also send frames
>   to the client or stop the connection.
>
> The following snippet forwards log messages to the client and ignores
>   all others:

```
websocket_info({log, Text}, State) ->
    {reply, {text, Text}, State};
websocket_info(_Info, State) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

So all you have to do is send a message to your handler from another process (or from itself if you wish), and implement websocket_info as above to send a frame to the client.